# Discord.py | Pillow ImageFilter

Tags: изображения, discord, discord.py, pillow

Задача кода:
При использовании команды бот берет фотографию пользователя или того, кого пользователь отметил, и добавляет эффект размытия.

Проблема кода:
Просмотрев довольно много источников, чтобы выполнить свою задачу, я не смог найти подробного ответа. На мой взгляд, мой код выглядит нормально, но он не работает, но, несмотря на то, ошибка не выводится.

Код:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

@Bot.command()
async def blur(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
    async with ctx.channel.typing():
        await ctx.message.delete()
        url = user.avatar_url
        image = Image.open(url)
        blurred_url = image.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
        blurred_url.save("sas.png")
        file = discord.File("sas.png", filename="sas.png")
        await ctx.send(file=file)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно ошибка у вас не выводится потому что вы даже не запустили бота)

По крайней мере в конце вашего кода я не вижу строчки `Bot.run('TOKEN')` или чего-то такого.

**Далее к проблемам кода**

---

Первая проблема в том, что у вас по умолчанию, если не указан аргумент `user`, он принимает значение `None`. На этот случай нужно добавить условие проверки:

```
if user is None:
    # значит нужно размыть аватарку автора
else:
    # нужно размыть аватарку указанного пользователя
```

В противном случае бот будет пытаться размыть аватарку только объекта `user`, а объект `None` является пустым и не имеет атрибута `avatar_url`, соответственно, строка `url = user.avatar_url` работать не будет.

**Об этом и сообщает `discord-py`:**

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'avatar_url'
```

**Данная проблема решается одной строкой:**

```
if user is None: user = ctx.author
```

*Если user пустой, то он принимает значение автора сообщения*

---

Следующая проблема заключается в том, что вы пытаетесь считать картинку по ссылке, в то время как библиотеке требуется локальная картинка на вашем компьютере. То есть, `bytes-like object`, объект, который можно считать по отдельным битам.

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'coroutine'
```

Для решения этой проблемы достаточно просто скачать указанную картинку - прямая ссылка у вас уже есть:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

url = user.avatar_url                                      # ссылка на аватарку пользователя
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})  # эти параметры нужно передать дискорду, чтобы он думал, что заходит реальный человек - в противном случае не будет доступа
resource = urlopen(req)                                    # открываем картинку
avatar = open("avatar", 'wb')                              # записываем картинку в файл
avatar.write(resource.read())
avatar.close()                                             # закрываем файл
```

Затем все тоже самое, но открываем уже конкретный файл:

```
image = Image.open('avatar.png')
```

---

**Готово! Результат:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Полный код:**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents = discord.Intents.all())

@Bot.command()
async def blur(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
    if user is None: user = ctx.author
    async with ctx.channel.typing():
        await ctx.message.delete()
        url = user.avatar_url
        req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
        resource = urlopen(req)
        avatar = open("avatar.png", 'wb')
        avatar.write(resource.read())
        avatar.close()
        image = Image.open('avatar.png')
        blurred_url = image.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
        blurred_url.save("sas.png")
        file = discord.File("sas.png", filename="sas.png")
        await ctx.send(file=file)

Bot.run('TOKEN')
```

**Не забудьте указать токен!**

Comment: Спасибо, все работает. По поводу токена, нет все есть. Я просто отправил только отдельный код который касается моей задачи и по этому он так выглядит. Я пытался так же сделать через if но увы мой уровень не на столько высок. Спасибо что решили. 
И кстати, просто на будущее. Есть способ чтоб настроить силу размытия?

Comment: Все, я решил свою задачу.

Изменил это:
`blurred_url = image.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)`
На это:
`blurred_url = image.filter(ImageFilter.BoxBlur(10))`